# Keyboard shortcuts to navigate Asana board view?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, asana

In Asana, I cannot use keyboard shortcuts to navigate in the board view. Am I missing something?

The shortcuts on [this page](https://asana.com/guide/help/faq/shortcuts) do not work (up and down arrows).
My goal is to navigate between tasks of the columns of my board.

Comment: Using the up down arrows has no effect in task view or dash view. Mac or Linux. US keyboard